# Difference between `values` & `getValues` on Raster in R

Tags: r, raster

I have a Raster Layer read into R.

What is the difference between the below `values` which gives me a min of 0 and max of 289, and `getValues()` which gives me a minimum of 0 and maximum of 7?

```
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 200, 200, 40000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 200, 0, 200  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
values      : 0, 289  (min, max)

 [1] 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
 [43] 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 0 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
 [85] 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
```

In short, would like to know the difference in what the 2 types of min/max values refer to, since they seem to be referring to different things.

Comment: As per documentation: `values` _is a shorthand version of_ `getValues` _(for all rows)_  - so basically there should be no difference if you call it correctly. What's the function call which produces the vector you added above?

Comment: The function call for the top portion is `map` (my Raster variable) that produced values of 0(min) and 289 (max), while the function call for the bottom portion is `getValues(map)` that produced values of 0 & 7.

Comment: `getValues(map)` would return all values of `map`, which would be 40000 values, too much for the console to handle. Did you assign it to a variable and see what the real distribution of values is? I'm assuming there's more than just 0s and 7s

Comment: Yes I did plot a histogram, and it showed only values of either 0 or 7... (no values in between either). 7 is the dominant value.

Comment: there's cases where the min/max in the `values` slot of the raster object can be wrong - i.e. just an estimate for display ... to get a definite value you should run either `summary(map)` or `cellStats(map,'min')` and `cellStats(map,'max')` ... otherwhise it's hard to tell without having the data

Comment: When I run `summary(map)`, the results as follows though...

`Min.                        0
1st Qu.                     7
Median                      7
3rd Qu.                     7
Max.                        7
NA's                        0`

Comment: what does `freq` of this raster layer show?

Comment: `freq(map)` gives the following:

     `value count
[1,]     0  2263
[2,]     1     1
[3,]     2     5
[4,]     3     8
[5,]     4     9
[6,]     5     9
[7,]     6     8
[8,]     7 37697`